# some jquery code not working when bootstrap hidden tab comes active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using owl carousel and bootstrap in my project, I also modify synchronised owl carousel according to my need, and put two owl carousel in bootstrap tabs, on default tab this works fine, but when I switch tab, jquery code which I write don't work.

[Please refer code-pen link](http://codepen.io/Aditya055/pen/egowga).

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(){

   var sync1 = $("#sync11");
   var sync2 = $("#sync21");

   sync1.owlCarousel({
    singleItem : true,
    slideSpeed : 1000,
    navigation: true,
    pagination:false,
    afterAction : syncPosition,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
  });

   sync2.owlCarousel({
    items : 5,

    pagination:false,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
    afterInit : function(el){
      el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
    }
  });

   function syncPosition(el){
    var current = this.currentItem;
    $("#sync21")
    .find(".owl-item")
    .removeClass("synced")
    .eq(current)
    .addClass("synced")
    if($("#sync21").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
      center(current)
    }

  }

  $("#sync21").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
    sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
  });

  function center(number){
    var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
    var num = number;
    var found = false;
    for(var i in sync2visible){
      if(num === sync2visible[i]){
        var found = true;
      }
    }

    if(found===false){
      if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+2)
      }else{
        if(num - 1 === -1){
          num = 0;
        }
        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
      }
    } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
      sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
    } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
      sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1)
    }
  }
});

  var sync1 = $("#sync1");
  var sync2 = $("#sync2");

  sync1.owlCarousel({
    singleItem : true,
    slideSpeed : 1000,
    navigation: true,
    pagination:false,
    afterAction : syncPosition,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
  });

  sync2.owlCarousel({
    items : 5,
    pagination:false,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
    afterInit : function(el){
      el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
    }
  });

  function syncPosition(el){
    var current = this.currentItem;
    $("#sync2")
    .find(".owl-item")
    .removeClass("synced")
    .eq(current)
    .addClass("synced")
    if($("#sync2").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
      center(current)
    }
  }

  $("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
    sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
  });

  function center(number){
    var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;

    var num = number;
    var found = false;
    for(var i in sync2visible){
      if(num === sync2visible[i]){
        var found = true;
      }
    }

    if(found===false){
      if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+2)
      }else{
        if(num - 1 === -1){
          num = 0;
        }
        sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
      }
    } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
      sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
    } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
      sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1)
    }
  }
```

My script:

```
  var all = $(".side .owl-wrapper .owl-item ").length;
  console.log(all);
  var height1 = $(".side .owl-wrapper .owl-item ").height();
  var height = $(".side .owl-wrapper .owl-item ").height() * 5;
  $(".side .owl-wrapper").css("height", height +"px");
  var syncposi = $(".side .owl-wrapper .synced").index();
  console.log(syncposi);
  if (syncposi ==0) {
    $(".owl-prev").css({"pointer-events":"none", "opacity":0.3});
  }

  $(".owl-next").click(function(){
   var index = $(".side .owl-wrapper .synced").index();
   if (index > 4 && index <=22) { 
    $('.side .owl-wrapper').animate({scrollTop:'+='+height1});

  }
  $(".owl-prev").css({"pointer-events":"auto", "opacity":1});
  if(index==0) {
    $('.side .owl-wrapper').scrollTop(0);
    console.log("hi");
  }
});
  $(".owl-prev").click(function(){
   var index = $(".side .owl-wrapper .synced").index();
   if (index >5) {
    $('.side .owl-wrapper').animate({scrollTop:'-='+height1});
  }
  if (index <2) {
    $('.side .owl-wrapper').animate({scrollTop:'-='+height1*2});
  }

  if (index ==0) {
    $(".owl-prev").css({"pointer-events":"none", "opacity":0.3});
  }
});

  setInterval(function(){
    var syncposi = $(".side .owl-wrapper .synced").index();
    if (syncposi ==0) {
      $(".owl-prev").css({"pointer-events":"none", "opacity":0.3});
    }
  },100);

});
```

Comment: I need carousel in second tab should work like in first tab

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: For synchronised right side vertical slider I have set set height equal to 5 images, also when slide index reaches to 5, right side slider also scrolls up, this works fine in first tab named "menu", but same code not working in second tab (Menu 1). Please refer codepen.

Comment: I have done it, it is very interesting to play with jQuery.